# Does the sample mean fit in sampling distribution

Tags: statistics, sampling

I'm not too sure whether my understanding is correct about this question I have so I'll ask it here.

Given this graph:
[image: Sampling distribution]

I have a sample mean of 377.4. Does it belong in the sampling distribution?

For my answer, I assume it does fit in the sampling distribution because it is still within the min max range of the sampling distribution values. Furthermore, the sample mean of 377.4 is statistically significant because it falls outside the confidence interval and within the critical region, beyond 376.8.

Is my answer a correct assumption? Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Overall, a reasonable interpretation.

Comment: I have never heard of any statistic being described as "belonging in the sampling distribution."  The meaning of such a phrase is unclear.  Claiming that this sample does not "belong" in the sampling distribution makes absolutely no sense.  Such statements are absurd and reflects a failure to use correct statistical terminology.

Comment: Cross-post:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/471718/119261.

Answer (score 1):

After some shifting around, turns out that the sample mean of 377.4 does not fit inside the sampling distribution because it exists outside the confidence interval. That still means it is statistically significant.